# How can I use devise to send a reset password link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I currently have an app that allows users to invite other users to their organization. How can I make it so that devise will send a reset password link to the users that have been invited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add *recoverable* and use the [send_reset_password_instructions](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable%3asend_reset_password_instructions) method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :recoverable
  ...
end
```

`User.find(1).send_reset_password_instructions`

Comment: Is there an example of this implementation? I'm new to devise

Comment: Thanks. So in my specific case, I would have a form that lets you enter the email of a user that I want to invite to my org. Then when they submit that I create the user and attach it to the same org and send the password reset instructions. Would that make sense?